# Change width UIView by animation and center

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a view and need change width from 100 to 200 by animation.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5
            ,animations: {
                    self.backgroundPlaceHolderView.frame.size.width += 200
})
```

when running this code, my view change width, but I need a change in width from the center, but this code increase view to the right
[image]

Comment: Can you show us how the animation looks right now? You should center align the view for it to animate from the center.

Comment: You should also decrease `X Position` of view.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri update question

Comment: @RasoulMiri since you are working with frames, try what sagar suggested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really need to do it with frames, here's a code snippet:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.backgroudPlaceHolderView.frame.origin.x -= 100
        self.backgroudPlaceHolderView.frame.size.width += 200
    })
```

Answer (score 6):

If you moved from manipulating the frame to manipulating constraints this would be easier and cleaner in my opinion.

1. In the InterfaceBuilder (or programmatically) center your `UIView` horizontally.
2. Outlet your width constraint (which would begin at 100).

When you want to increase the width of your `UIView` you can do the following;

```
view.layoutIfNeeded() // always make sure any pending layout changes have happened

widthConstraint.constant = 200

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Autolayout will take care of the rest for you. Your view is centered horizontally so it should expand from the center.

Answer (score 2):

You should have that backgroundPlaceHolderView constrained on the centerX. It's probably anchored on the left.